# Cython cannot convert to Python object

Tags: python, cython, python-object

```
cdef class Y:

    cdef double* _ptr

    def __cinit__(self, double* ptr):
        self._ptr = ptr

cdef class X:

    cdef double* _ptr

    def __cinit__(self):
        # some magic with _ptr
        self._y = Y(self._ptr)
```

Cannot convert `double *` to `Python` object

Why does this happen? Is there a nicer way of fixing this other than passing the whole `X` object to `Y` and extracting _ptr by hand?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cython: "Cannot convert Python object" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47005382/cython-cannot-convert-python-object-error)

Comment: Not really, my question is specifically about cdef classes with __cinit__ constructors, which in theory should support passing cdef arguments somehow

Comment: Unfortunately I’m afraid that the answer to my question is that __cinit__ is def not cdef, so there is no elegant, no-overhead way to solve it

Comment: The usual way to solve this is to make a `cdef` staticmethod (e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19370230/cython-overloaded-constructor-initialization-using-raw-pointer)

Comment: Wouldn’t classmethod be even more suitable?

Comment: I don't think classmethod is supported for cdef functions